# Using ui:repeat to iterate over columns

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm in `Mojarra 2.1.29`.

I tried to iterate over the collection to produce amount of rows equals to the size of the collection. Here what I've tried:

```
<rich:dataTable id="table"
                       var="partner"
                       rows="10"
                       value="#{testBean.k}">

    <ui:repeat var="name" value="#{testBean.cols}"> 
           <rich:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="#{name}"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{m.get(partner)}"/>
               <f:facet name="footer">
                   <h:outputText value="#{name}}"/>
               </f:facet>
           </rich:column>
    </ui:repeat>
</rich:dataTable>
```

`testBean.cols` was initalized as follows:

```
public class TestBean{
    private List<String> cols = new ArrayList<>();

    public TestBean() {
        cols.add("Col 1");
        cols.add("Col 2");
    }
}
```

It didn't work. As the result a got a table with `0` columns. What was wrong and is there a way to fix that?

I've made sure that the expression `#{partnerListController.cols}` resolved to a non-empty list by putting it in the markup and getting `[Col 1, Col 2]`.

Why can't I iterate over such lists?

Comment: tried using c:foreach instead of ui:repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `c:foreach` instead of `ui:repeat` as suggested by @Kukeltje will probably work, but the proper way to create dynamic columns by iterating over a `Collection` would rather be using the `<rich:columns>` component.

From https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columns.html:

> The `<rich:columns>` component gets a list from data model and outputs
>   a corresponding set of columns inside `<rich:dataTable>` on a page. It
>   is possible to use "header" and "footer" facets with `<rich:columns>`
>   component.
>
> The "value" and "var" attributes are used to access the values of
>   collection.

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{testBean.k}" var="partner" id="table" rows="10">
   <rich:columns value="#{testBean.cols}" var="name">
           <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText value="#{name}"/>
           </f:facet>
           <h:outputText value="#{m.get(partner)}"/>
           <f:facet name="footer">
               <h:outputText value="#{name}"/>
           </f:facet>>
   </rich:columns>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: Remarkable…  a few months ago for a different SO post, I searched for this but dit not find it (I'm no RF user) and was surprised it was not there. Good to know